# Font Not Initialised Error When Running Outside Of Function Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, chess

I'm currently writing a chess program in pygame and I'm trying to display text on the screen when someone makes an invalid move. However, when I make the code initialise the font inside of the loop that draws the pieces on the screen, it takes 8 seconds to initialise the font every time someone makes a mistake, making the experience sluggish and slow.

The code that I've got at the moment has the font initialisation taking place at the top of the program but then the error *font has not been initialised* appears constantly and I've got no idea why. Any help on the issue would be great!

Written using python and the pygame module by the way.

```
import pygame as p
from Kess import chessEngine

WIDTH = HEIGHT = 512  # 512 is a power of 2 and is easily divisible by 8 for the squares of the ui
DIMENSION = 8
SQ_SIZE = HEIGHT // DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 15  # for animations - may be able to delete later
IMAGES = {}
WHITE = (237, 240, 207)
BLACK = (108, 155, 79)
TEXT_COLOUR = (0, 0, 0)
MOVING = False
invalid = False
gs = chessEngine.GameState()
font = p.font.SysFont('timesnewromanbold', 32)


'''

Global dictionary of images which will be called once. Can contain multiple image sets for theme
customisation

'''


def load_images():
    pieces = ["bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "bP",
              "wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK", "wP"]
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load("images/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
        #  The p.transform.scale function scales the imported images to fit the dimensions of the square
        #  The for loop allows for the pieces to be imported together rather than a long list of individual calls.


def main():
    global player_click_region
    p.init()
    #  Initiates the pygame.
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    #  Sets the display screen to be 512x512 as the set variables at the top of the file.
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    #  Starts the inbuilt chess clock.
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    #  Sets a background with a colour of white.
    load_images()
    running = True
    #  This while loop draws the black tiles on the board by alternating the beginning x value (beginning 64x64
    #  square coordinate) and then skipping a tile (white tile) and doing the same.
    draw_pieces(screen)
    square_selected = ()  # Keeps track of what square in what row/column the user has currently selected
    player_click_region = []  # Keeps track of original square and destination square e.g. (2, 4) (4, 2)

    while running:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in p.event.get():
            if event.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.type == p.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                location = p.mouse.get_pos()  # Returns (x,y) pos of mouse
                #  print(location)
                column = location[0] // SQ_SIZE
                row = location[1] // SQ_SIZE
                #  print(row, column)
                if square_selected == (row, column):
                    square_selected = ()
                    player_click_region = []
                else:
                    square_selected = (row, column)
                    player_click_region.append(square_selected)
                    #  print(piece)
                if len(player_click_region) == 2:
                    location = p.mouse.get_pos()
                    piece = gs.board[player_click_region[0][0]][player_click_region[0][1]]
                    valid_move(piece)
                    destination_column = location[0] // SQ_SIZE
                    destination_row = location[1] // SQ_SIZE
                    if invalid is True:
                        print("INVALID MOVE: PLEASE TRY AGAIN")
                    else:
                        gs.board[destination_row][destination_column] = piece
                        gs.board[player_click_region[0][0]][player_click_region[0][1]] = "--"
                    player_click_region = []
                    square_selected = ()
                    print(gs.board)
        draw_pieces(screen)
        p.display.update()

#  Update board using pairs of tuples...


def draw_pieces(screen):
    global font
    x = 1
    y = 0
    while y < DIMENSION:
        while x < DIMENSION:
            p.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (x * SQ_SIZE, y * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
            #  Ask Mr. Clarke how to access a specific list within a class of another file and then how to get an index
            #  from within that list.
            x += 2
        if x == 9:
            x = 0
        else:
            x = 1
        y += 1
    y = 0
    x = 0
    while y < DIMENSION:
        while x < DIMENSION:
            p.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (x * SQ_SIZE, y * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
            #  Ask Mr. Clarke how to access a specific list within a class of another file and then how to get an index
            #  from within that list.
            x += 2
        if x == 9:
            x = 0
        else:
            x = 1
        y += 1
    y = 0
    x = 0
    while y < DIMENSION:
        while x < DIMENSION:
            piece = gs.board[y][x]
            if piece != "--":
                screen.blit(IMAGES[piece], (x * SQ_SIZE, y * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
            #  Ask Mr. Clarke how to access a specific list within a class of another file and then how to get an index
            #  from within that list.
            x += 1
        x = 0
        y += 1

    if invalid is True:
        text = font.render('INVALID MOVE', True, TEXT_COLOUR)
        screen.blit(text, (HEIGHT/2, WIDTH/2))


def valid_move(piece):
    global invalid
    # print(gs.board[player_click_region[1][0]][player_click_region[1][1]])
    invalid = False
    change_x = abs(player_click_region[0][0] - player_click_region[1][0])  # abs() finds absolute value - always pos
    change_y = abs(player_click_region[0][1] - player_click_region[1][1])
    linear_x = player_click_region[0][0] - player_click_region[1][0]
    #  linear_y = player_click_region[0][1] - player_click_region[1][1]
    destination_piece = gs.board[player_click_region[1][0]][player_click_region[1][1]]
    print("x change", str(change_x))
    print("y change", str(change_y))
    if piece[0] == destination_piece[0]:
        invalid = True
        print("invalid 3")
    if "P" in piece:
        if change_x != 1 and change_x != 2:
            invalid = True
        else:
            if player_click_region[0][0] != 6 and player_click_region[0][0] != 1:
                if change_x == 2:
                    invalid = True
            if "b" in piece:
                if player_click_region[0][0] == 1:
                    if gs.board[player_click_region[0][0]+1][player_click_region[0][1]] != "--":
                        invalid = True
                    if linear_x > 0:
                        invalid = True
            if "w" in piece:
                if player_click_region[0][0] == 6:
                    if gs.board[player_click_region[0][0]-1][player_click_region[0][1]] != "--":
                        invalid = True
                        print("1")
                if linear_x < 0:
                    invalid = True
                    print("2")
            if invalid is False:
                if change_y == 0:
                    if destination_piece != "--":
                        invalid = True
        if change_y == 1:
            if change_x != 1:
                invalid = True
            if destination_piece == "--":
                invalid = True
            else:
                print("capturing now")
        if change_y > 1:
            invalid = True

    if "B" in piece:
        if change_x != change_y:
            invalid = True
            print("you don messed up boy")
        else:
            i = 1
            if linear_x < 0:
                for i in range(i, change_x):
                    if gs.board[player_click_region[0][0]+i][player_click_region[0][1]+i] != "--":
                        invalid = True
                    i += 1
                i = 1
            if linear_x > 0:
                for i in range(i, change_x):
                    if gs.board[player_click_region[0][0]-i][player_click_region[0][1]-i] != "--":
                        invalid = True

    if "N" in piece:
        if change_x + change_y != 3:
            invalid = True
        if change_x > 0 and change_y > 0:
            if destination_piece != "--":
                print("capture_piece()")
        else:
            invalid = True

    if "R" in piece:
        if change_x > 0 and change_y > 0:
            invalid = True
        else:
            x = 1
            if change_x > 0:
                for x in range(x, change_x):
                    print(player_click_region[0][0]+x)
                    if player_click_region[0][0] > player_click_region[1][0]:
                        print("now uve done messed up")
                        if gs.board[player_click_region[1][0]+x][player_click_region[1][1]] != "--":
                            invalid = True
                    else:
                        print(gs.board[player_click_region[0][0] + x][player_click_region[0][1]])
                        if gs.board[player_click_region[0][0]+x][player_click_region[0][1]] != "--":
                            print(gs.board[player_click_region[0][0]+x][player_click_region[0][1]])
                            invalid = True
                    x+=1
            else:
                for x in range(x, change_y-1):
                    print(player_click_region)
                    if player_click_region[0][1] > player_click_region[1][1]:
                        if gs.board[player_click_region[1][0]][player_click_region[1][1]+x] != "--":
                            invalid = True
                    else:
                        if gs.board[player_click_region[0][0]][player_click_region[0][1]+x] != "--":
                            invalid = True
                        x+=1

    if "Q" in piece:
        print(change_x, change_y)
        if change_x == change_y:
            print("how does this work")
            i = 1
            if linear_x < 0:
                for i in range(i, change_x):
                    if gs.board[player_click_region[0][0] + i][player_click_region[0][1] + i] != "--":
                        invalid = True
                        print("invalid 2")
                    i += 1
                i = 1
            if linear_x > 0:
                for i in range(i, change_x):
                    if gs.board[player_click_region[0][0] - i][player_click_region[0][1] - i] != "--":
                        invalid = True
                        print("invalid 1")
        elif change_x + change_y == 1:
            if destination_piece != "--":
                print("Capture")
                # Check whether the piece taken is the same colour or not
            else:
                print("Empty Square")

        else:
            print("fucked up")
            if change_x > 0 and change_y > 0:
                invalid = True
            else:
                x = 1
                if change_x > 0:
                    for x in range(x, change_x):
                        if player_click_region[0][0] > player_click_region[1][0]:
                            if gs.board[player_click_region[1][0] + x][player_click_region[1][1]] != "--":
                                invalid = True
                        else:
                            if gs.board[player_click_region[0][0] + x][player_click_region[0][1]] != "--":
                                invalid = True
                        x += 1
                else:
                    for x in range(x, change_y - 1):
                        print(player_click_region)
                        if player_click_region[0][1] > player_click_region[1][1]:
                            if gs.board[player_click_region[1][0]][player_click_region[1][1] + x] != "--":
                                invalid = True
                        else:
                            if gs.board[player_click_region[0][0]][player_click_region[0][1] + x] != "--":
                                invalid = True
                            x += 1

    if "K" in piece:
        if change_x > 1 or change_y > 1:
            invalid = True



#  To implement the images. the coordinates of the tiles are 64x64 and you can multiply them by a number for the x value
#  which would then move them over a certain number of tiles (e.g. 64*3 would give 3 tiles to the right), and same for
#  the y values.

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the `font` module, before you can use it:

```py
p.font.init()
font = p.font.SysFont('timesnewromanbold', 32)
```

Alternatively you can initialize all pygame modules:

```py
p.init()
font = p.font.SysFont('timesnewromanbold', 32)
```

Or create the `font` object in `main` after `p.init()`:

```py
def main():
    global player_click_region
    global font
    p.init()
    font = p.font.SysFont('timesnewromanbold', 32)

    # [...]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this one line issue for hours, I greatly appreciate it!